# codeigniter emoji picker js not loading

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I'm developing a chat like web application where users can comment their text.Now I want to add emojis in the comment box.My code in main layout to load emoji js,

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>scripts/libraries/jquery.emojipicker.js"></script>
   <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>scripts/libraries/jquery.emojis.js"></script> 

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(e) {

  $('#editor-textarea').emojiPicker();
  $('#feed-comment-input').emojiPicker();
  $('#input-default').emojiPicker();

  $('#input-custom-size').emojiPicker({
    width: '300px',
    height: '200px'
  });

  $('#input-left-position').emojiPicker({
    position: 'left'
  });

  $('#create').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#text-custom-trigger').emojiPicker({
      width: '300px',
      height: '200px',
      button: false
    });
  });

  $('#toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#text-custom-trigger').emojiPicker('toggle');
  });

  $('#destroy').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#text-custom-trigger').emojiPicker('destroy');
  })

  // keyup event is fired
  $(".emojiable-question, .emojiable-option").on("keyup", function () {
    //console.log("emoji added, input val() is: " + $(this).val());
  });

});
```

I'm using foreach to load all posts,like

```
<?php foreach($posts->result() as $r) : ?>
  ....<posts>...

  <div class="field">
  <input type="text" id="input-default" class="emojiable-option" placeholder="Default">
</div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

How to load js for all the posts (foreach)

The emoji should load for everypost but it loads only for the first post only.I can't guess why it's not loaded for other post's comment.Or what's the problem with foreach?Can anybody help me to solve this issue?

Or Passing the element directly in emojipicker.js 'll solve the probem?Like,

```
function EmojiPicker( element, options ) {
 this.$el = $('textarea');
.....
}
```

Comment: You should add the `javascript` tag to your question

Comment: not sure a chat system sounds like an async application - could it be that you've to delegate the `emojiPicker` function instead of calling once - because if you dnyamically load this content via ajax - that part of the dom wouldn't be affected ...

Comment: Should I load the  emojipicker ` $('#editor-textarea').emojiPicker();
  $('#feed-comment-input').emojiPicker();
  $('#input-default').emojiPicker();` via ajax?

Comment: can you try these are some jquery emoji with an example? https://jqueryhouse.com/10-jquery-emoji-plugins/

Comment: I can but whatever I 've tried couldn't give the result without loading this jquery.That's what is an issue here.When I change the `this.$el = $('textarea');` directly in emojipicker,results load the picker in some more posts.But not for all (: